# Para que serve o atributo size_hint_x em Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Durante meus estudos no framework Kivy, eu descobri dois atributos do objeto `BoxLayout` chamados `size_hint_x`e `size_hint_y` que pelo o que dizem, eles adequam o tamanho de um widget para o tamanho da tela (até faz sentido pois sua tradução seria "dica de tamanho").

Logo eu pensei que `size_hint_x` e `size_hint_y` recebessem somente os valores `True` e `False` para ligar ou desliga-los. Porém vendo alguns código na internet, eu me deparei com valores numéricos sendo passados como argumento. Exemplo:

```
widget.size_hint_x = 0.3
widget.size_hint_y = 5
```

Então agora vai o título dessa question: O que são exatamente os atributos `size_hint` e qual sua utilidade ?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=size_hint#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint):

> size_hint é uma [ReferenceListProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty) para as propriedades (size_hint_x, size_hint_y).

Ou seja, o `size_hint` recebe uma tupla no qual vai ser atribuído para `size_hint_x` e `size_hint_y`, seguindo esta forma:

```
size_hint = ReferenceListProperty(size_hint_x, size_hint_y)
```

No fonte há esta descrição:

> O atributo `size_hint` é uma tupla de valores usadas pelo layout para gerenciar o tamanho de seus filhos, ele indica o tamanho relativo do layout ao invés do tamanho absoluto em pixels, points, cm, etc.

Consulte a [definição](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/52d12ebf33e410c9f4798674a93cbd0db8038bf1/kivy/uix/widget.py#L1181) no fonte.

Comment: Sim eu sei sobre isso. O que eu quero saber é o que faz exatamente o `(size_hint,x,size_hint_y)` no aplicativo. O que são esses valores ? É possível explicar melhor isso com mais detalhes ?

Comment: Você perguntou sobre `size_hint`, ele é apenas a referencia para `size_hint_x` e `size_hint_y` para definir o tamanho do widget em relação ao filho.

Comment: Esta bem, vou melhorar a pergunta tudo bem ?

Answer (score 1):

size_hint_x é a largura que um widget filho tem em relação à largura disponível no widget pai.

Digamos que o seu código tenha um BoxLayout e você queira colocar dois botões nele, sendo que o segundo botão terá o dobro da largura do primeiro botão:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Aplicativo(App):
    def build(self):
        caixa = BoxLayout()
        botao_0 = Button(text='BOTAO_0', size_hint_x=1)
        botao_1 = Button(text='BOTAO_1', size_hint_x=2)

        caixa.add_widget(botao_0)
        caixa.add_widget(botao_1)

        return caixa


Aplicativo().run()
```

[image: Captura de tela com código executado em uma janela mostrando 2 botões, um ao lado do outro, sendo que o da direita tem aproximadamente o dobro da largura do primeiro]

Se você quiser determinar uma largura fixa, específica para o segundo botão (widget filho do BoxLayout), independente da largura disponível do pai, terá que desligar essa propriedade escrevendo size_hint_x = None (None é o nulo do Python) e depois, por exemplo, escrever width = 100

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Aplicativo(App):
    def build(self):
        caixa = BoxLayout()
        botao_0 = Button(text='BOTAO_0', size_hint_x=1)
        botao_1 = Button(text='BOTAO_1', size_hint_x=None, width=100)

        caixa.add_widget(botao_0)
        caixa.add_widget(botao_1)

        return caixa


Aplicativo().run()
```

[image: Captura de tela apresentando uma janela com 2 botões, sendo que o da direita é muito mais estreito que o da esquerda.]

Observe que o código do primeiro botão não foi alterado.

Utilizei Python 3.7, Kivy 1.11.1 e PyCharm Community 2020.2